# How to protect code from system-change date?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to protect code from system-change date, for example I use simple script to check if date is "expired", but if user system date is changed before defined date this becomes absurdly. Please help, I am new in this area :)

```
var GivenDate = new Date('31/12/2021');
var CurrentDate = new Date();
if(GivenDate > CurrentDate){
/// do anything...
}
else{
alert("Your licence has expired!")
}
```

Comment: In JavaScript no, the client can do whatever they want

Comment: If there is a resource you are limiting using date logic it would be wiser to implement the logic on the backend, eg if a person has not paid a subscription they will not be able to get a response if they request for e.g a video course

Comment: If you need an accurate date, call an API and retrieve from a server you trust or own. As @Craques mentions, important date-based logic should always be - at the very least - checked on the server to verify the client did not manipulate the data. Similar to how you can provide client-side validations for form data, but still need to re-validate on servers.

Comment: It seems interesting to me, there is a server that I trust and that all users are connected to, but can you help me how to do it?